# Getting error Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code here for a webpage I'm fooling around with:

```
$(function() {
    console.log('Here');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://api.bf3stats.com/pc/playerlist/',
        data: {
            players: ['xxx', 'xxxx', 'x']
        },
        success: function(data) {
            loadData(data, 'x', 'f');

        }
    })
})

function loadData(data, uname, $) {
    $('#fWins').text("135");
}
```

But once it hits the `loadData` function I get the error:

```
Error: Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function
```

I'm absolutely clueless as to why this is giving me so much problems. Thanks in advance!

Thanks problem was me using $, I don't use jQuery often, only for when i need cross browser compatibility. Thanks for this, will mark Answered when timer is up

Comment: why $ in `(data, uname, $)` ?

Comment: It's not that third parameter name on `loadData` is it? JQuery may be getting confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using `$` as the parameter name for the last param in loadData. This means your function will use the string "f" that you're passing to the function when it sees the `$` on `$('#fWins').text("135");` instead of using jQuery, so it's essentially doing this: `"f"('#fWins').text("135");` To fix it, change:

```
function loadData(data, uname, $) {
```

to something like

```
function loadData(data, uname, lastParam) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    console.log('Here');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://api.bf3stats.com/pc/playerlist/',
        data: {
            players: ['xxx', 'xxxx', 'x']
        },
        success: function (data) {
            loadData(data, 'x', 'f');

        }
    });
});

function loadData(data, uname, param) {
    console.log('Here too..');
    $('#fWins').text("135");
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ThVE6/1/) *( In the console you will get both **Here** & **Here too..**, without any error )*

Answer (score 0):

the $ is trying to pass that variable as a function
so if you had a function declared with the string being passed it would fire it

any reason why you want $ there?